# Does the spacetime curvature in the vicinity of a massive body increase, decrease or remain unchanged with the increasing velocity of an observer?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, curvature

Does the spacetime curvature in the vicinity of a massive body such as the sun increase, decrease or remain unchanged with respect to an observer's increasing velocity relative to that massive body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curvature of the spacetime geometry most often is expressed in terms of curvature invariant, examples are the Kretschmann scalar, the Chern–Pontryagin scalar and the Euler scalar. Look at [the discussion in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature_invariant_(general_relativity)).

The scalar invariants are the same for all observers, regardless of their velocity.