# Is the Earth's Orbit Slower When Big Ben is Time Dilated?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, reference-frames, orbital-motion, observers

Either way, the answer to this question has the most profound consequences imaginable.  Therefore the question will be asked in a more concrete manner:

Consider a distant observer traveling at .867c relative to the solar system, along the line that is collinear with the sun's axis of rotation.  That way the major and minor semi-axes of the earth's orbit remain undistorted by Lorentz contraction from the standpoint of the distant observer.  The distant observer watches Big Ben in London with a powerful telescope.  Allowing for relativistic doppler the distance observer measures Big Ben to be keeping time at half the rate of the distant observer's proper time wristwatch, in accordance with special relativity.  Does Big Ben's little hand still make 730.5 revolutions for every revolution that the earth makes around the sun?  Or is Big Ben's little hand no longer synchronized with the earth's orbit around the sun?

Comment: You mentioned the direction of travel and its effect on the appearance of Earth's orbit from the spaceship. Even though the distance hasn't changed, the measured orbital period will change -- to a naive observer that knew the mass of the sun, the length of the year would seem wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Alex.  I agree with your assessment so far.  But given the known mass of the sun, the first postulate, and the laws of physics, the distant observer will conclude that the earth is orbiting too slowly to maintain the size orbit that it currently occupies.  Could you address that aspect of my question?  Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not versed enough in general relativity to describe how you'd change the equations of motion for a moving observer/reference.

Answer (score 1):

In the coordinate system in which the distant spaceship is at rest, everything in the solar system is time dilated -- Big Ben, the Earth's orbit, the aging of humans, everything.

This isn't particularly profound though. It's very similar to the situation where you take a long thin ruler that's aligned along the Y axis, and then rotate the coordinate system by 45 degrees. Now suddenly the Y coordinate of the end of the ruler is smaller, and the X coordinate has become larger. You could attribute this to "Y contraction" and "X dilation", and in a sense you would be correct, but it's not a physical change to the ruler, it's just a coordinate effect.

Changing velocity is very similar to this, as it involves rotation of coordinates in spacetime, including the time coordinate. Nothing physically changes about the Earth when you measure it with the moving spaceship's coordinates, you just get a different mix of space and time values than you do when measuring in coordinates where the Earth is "at rest" (or nearly so).

Comment: Eric, thank you for your answer.  Addressing your first paragraph--if the earth's orbital period is in fact time dilated by gamma = 2 then please consider the consequences for the earth as it moves through the same spacetime curvature near the sun at only half the velocity of it's rest frame velocity.  In contrast to you, I believe this situation is quite profound.

Comment: Spacetime curvature involves both space *and* time, so you can't consider just the spatial components of Earth's velocity, you need to look at the velocity as a 4-vector. If you do so, you find the Earth's orbit is predicted to be the same regardless of which set of coordinates (moving or stationary) you choose to measure the velocity (and curvature!) in. This actually is pretty clear when you look at Einstein's field equations, but it does require some knowledge of differential geometry.

Comment: This is an excellent solution to the conundrum, Eric.  I wish you had put it into your answer.  Could you please add another answer that explains your solution in terms of 4-vectors with an example that demonstrates the earth's orbit is the same in all inertial frames.  Thank you.

Comment: The equations of general relativity are (by construction) invariant under change of reference frames; that was one of Einstein's main goals in building GR. Earth's orbit is a geodesic in spacetime, and will be in any reference frame. The particular coordinates used will be different of course, so coordinate dependent questions like "how long does an orbit take" may vary from frame to frame, but any coordinate independent question will get the same answer in all frames.

Comment: Eric, thanks again for another informative comment.  While general relativity certainly claims to provide the same answer in all frames, my example appears to demonstrate that the claim fails under the circumstances I propose.  But again I encourage you to demonstrate GR's claim to invariance in this specific example.  Perhaps in an additional answer where you will have more space to develop your thoughts?  It would be a great help to me and others.

Answer (score -3):

I must admit that I am taken aback by the -4 rating that my question received, inasmuch as it is a well researched and concisely expressed question which as far as I know, has never been addressed in any texts on special/general relativity and which explores the important intersection of special relativity with general relativity. I asked the question in this forum hoping to obtain an answer different from the two mutually exclusive and contradictory answers that I have thus far obtained via my own efforts.  I give those answers now.

In the first case I assume that from the standpoint of the distant observer the earth's orbit and Big Ben are time dilated to the same degree and so remain synchronized.  But with $\gamma = 2$ the earth is now orbiting through the same spacetime curvature

[Does the spacetime curvature in the vicinity of a massive body increase, decrease or remain unchanged with the increasing velocity of an observer?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/704815/does-the-spacetime-curvature-in-the-vicinity-of-a-massive-body-increase-decreas)

at only half the velocity it orbits in its rest frame. This is far too slow to sustain its orbit.

In the second place, if the earth's orbital velocity is not time dilated then the earth can successfully maintain its orbit. But now the distant observer measures that Big Ben and the earth's solar year are no longer synchronized.  This would seem an impossible state of affairs.

These are my two unsatisfactory answers to my unique, and as far as I know, never-asked-before question.  The one answer I have received does not appear to directly address the heart my question, and so has received no rating as of yet.  I earnestly await additional answers from all those who might have one.